# How to jump to emails starting with a specific initial letter of the sender?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

I'm opening my emails in Office365 and not in Outlook desktop app. Mail box size is around 49 GB. As a result it takes a long time to scroll through inbox and arrive at a particular letter. Is there a way to directly jump to a specific initial letter

eg P

without scrolling all the way from A to P or from Z to P?

Comment: Have you tried using the search function?

Comment: @DavidPostill it displays all the senders which contain the letter